# Access all elements in a pandas data frame to save as a file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a better way to access individual elements in a dataframe for it to be saved in a file?

This is my MCVE, does what I want, I am looking for a better way if possible.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col_1': [3,1,2,4], 'col_2': [7,6,5,8], 'col_3': [11,12,9,10]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
new_df = df.pivot_table(index=['col_2'],columns=['col_1'],values='col_3')
new_df.fillna( 0, inplace = True )

with open('result.txt','w') as f:
    for c1 in sorted(df.col_1.unique()):
        for c2 in sorted(df.col_2.unique()):
            f.writelines(' '.join(map(str,(c1, c2, new_df[c1][c2]))))
            f.write('\n')
```

Actual df does not have unique values in columns `c1` and `c2` and hence the need to do `df.cx.unique()`

Iterating is a last resort in pandas according to what I saw. My actual dataframe is 2000 rows and 1000 columns.

I am trying to get an output file like the following.

Output

```
1 5 0.0
1 6 12.0
1 7 0.0
1 8 0.0
2 5 9.0
2 6 0.0
2 7 0.0
2 8 0.0
3 5 0.0
3 6 0.0
3 7 11.0
3 8 0.0
4 5 0.0
4 6 0.0
4 7 0.0
4 8 10.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are after [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

So the solution looks something like (I have used your `new_df` from above after your pivot operation:

```
long_df = pd.melt(new_df.reset_index(), id_vars=["col_2"], value_vars=new_df.columns)
```

`print(long_df)` gives the solution that you are after (maybe requiring a renaming of the columns). You of course could also use `long_df.to_csv(file_name)` to store to a file instead of the loop that you have written.

Comment: I dont have access to the code right now, but thanks I will test this out and mark this as accepted if it does what I want